# Start screen isn't showing up

Tags: python, pygame, pong

After I got the paddles to move properly, the start screen stopped showing up at the beginning. I want it to show the actual game screen when you press enter, which worked, until I added the paddles. I know for a fact that the problem has to do with the display update, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's the game loop:

```py
while not x:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
      x = True #quits the game when you press X
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: #makes start screen go away
      if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        gameScreen() #has the black background and lines

  #moves the paddles
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_w: #makes blue paddle go up
        p1Paddle.state = 'up'
        p1Paddle.move()
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_s: #makes blue paddle go down
        p1Paddle.state = 'down'
        p1Paddle.move()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP: #makes red paddle go up
        p2Paddle.state = 'up'
        p2Paddle.move()
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: #makes red paddle go down
        p2Paddle.state = 'down'
        p2Paddle.move()

        
    gameScreen() #updates the display (problem- not sure what to put instead)
        
    p1Paddle.show()
    p2Paddle.show()
    ball.show()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### I fixed it! (sort of*)

I added a variable, `start`, before the loop and set it as false. Then, at the end of the loop I replaced this:

```
    gameScreen() #updates the display (problem- not sure what to put instead)
        
    p1Paddle.show()
    p2Paddle.show()
    ball.show()
```

with this:

```
    if start == True:
      gameScreen()
      p1Paddle.show() #make the paddles and ball show up vv
      p2Paddle.show()
      ball.show()
```

*Now the start screen shows up, but the paddles show up over it at the start- but that's it's own problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pygame.display.update()` instead of the gameScreen function to update the display. However, this doesn't seem to impact the game screen not showing. To fix the game screen not showing, try using the function `pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))` to set the screen's size and display it.

Some example code with the use of these functions is below. Try adding it at the very beginning of the entire code and see if it shows the game screen after pressing enter.

```
width = 500 #screen width
height = 200 #screen height
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: # show screen when enter key is pressed
    pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #creates screen
    gameScreen() # has the black background and lines
```

Comment: I don't think I worded the problem properly- sorry about that. The window itself shows up, but I want the gameScreen function, which draws the background of the game itself, to show up over the startScreen function (black screen that says press enter to start - I need a start screen for this assignment) when I press enter.